# What is the point of the name method in the symfony2 annotation?

Tags: symfony, model-view-controller, annotations, controllers

```
/**
*@Route ("/hello/{name}", name="_demo_hello")
*
**/
```

I saw this method in this youtube tutorial [Go to 7:36](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kspX0qOK9tY)
I wanted to know what is the significance of the "name" method? Can you make up the name method?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` option when defining routes with annotations is useful if you want to customize the name of the route. By default, if there is no `name` specified, Symfony will generate a name based on the controller's action name, like this:
`indexAction in the WebController of the AppBundle => app_web_index`

But you can use the name option to change that:

`@Route ("/", name="homepage")`

You can then use this name to refer to this route in your controllers or templates:

`{{ path('homepage') }}`